# Can we have multiple save file in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

Can we have multiple save files in this game? I mean, can I start a new game while keeping my last character's save?

Or is it a game with only 1 save file and you have to live with it?

Comment: You have the ability to create multiple characters on one profile, if that's what you mean...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you start a new game with a new character then you can use the "select character" option on the menu to go back to your first save file.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can create multiple *characters* to start new games and continue each independently. You can use New Game to start a new character or Select Character to play a previously made character; all their progress is saved.

However, you can't go back and load previous saves of existing characters; only the latest save per character is ever kept by default so all progress made is kept, so progress is 100% linear. I guess some fudging around with save files could eliminate this, but Borderlands isn't meant to be one of those RPGs where you have 500 save files for one character.

Comment: So if I join someone's game and it saves my save file that I had before will be deleted?

Comment: @Zed420 I wouldn't say it's "deleted" but it is immediately overwritten each time you see the hologram-looking Vault symbol/save icon on your screen

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said you can easily change characters in-game.
However you cannot change your profile(the profile that your badass rank is saved in) in-game.
If that is what you want to do then you need to manually move your savefiles to another folder and change the save files as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite simple, create multiple characters and name them accordingly. Then on the title menu select your character from the list on the right then press Y (on Xbox360) and a list of all your different characters will appear and select whichever one you want to use.