# 2 different saved games on borderland 2

Tags: borderlands-2

My son and I are playing Borderlands 2 in co op play. Is there a way that he or I can play a separate game on our own that will not affect our on line game? The other day he played for a while on his own and the next time we entered the game together it moved me further ahead in the game than I originally was.

Comment: Try going here!

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86290/can-we-have-multiple-save-file-in-borderlands-2