# Can I make a new character in Borderlands 2 without removing/overwriting any of the existing saves?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have not yet played any PS3 games before, but I want to play Borderlands 2. My dear hubby already has save games, which I'm afraid to accidentally overwrite or something when I start a new game.

Can I choose the same character without overwriting his or do I have to choose a different character than what he already has used?

I'd like to have my own save game completely separate from his, without anything being shared. Is this possible? I don't have my own PS3 account.

Comment: What does DH stand for?

Comment: DH means Dear Hubby

Comment: Do you have your own profile on the PS3 console?

Comment: No I do not have a profile on the PS3.

Comment: If it's the same account, you should be able to save in a different slot and start a new game... as far as I'm aware, skins are shared.  Having said that, I'm not sure if skins unlocked during the game are specific to the character you're playing as.

Comment: How can I save to a different slot?

Comment: @Powerlord I'm not sure that's correct... Looking at [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86290/can-we-have-multiple-save-file-in-borderlands-2#86292), it appears that if you start a new game for a character that already has a save, it overwrites the old one.

Comment: I do not want to overwrite the old save.

Comment: @newshooter I'm only familiar with the PC version of the game.  When you start that you have the option of Continue or New Game and as I recall, choosing New Game will ask you which save slot you want to use.  However, like king14nyr said, you can only have one save per character.

Comment: So, I guess it's more like you have 6 saves... one per character (note: 2 of the characters are from DLC).

Comment: When you start a new game you do not overwrite anything immediately, the only potential time for an overwrite is when you are saving for the first time. Make sure you save to a new file and you will be fine. You can play any character you want also, does not matter when someone else has played on the same system/profile. I have had various saves of the same characters going on before.

Comment: @Dupree3 yeah, the more I read up on it, I think this is correct... A lot of conflicting reports, since there seems to be some confusion on sharing regarding character, profile, etc. I think the answer I linked may actually be inaccurate, if the other resources I've read are correct. :\

Comment: Does Borderlands 2 have a physical save available during the game anytime or a specific save point? I have seen the machine that seems like a check point within the game when DH played is this an automatic save point as well?

Comment: @newshooter you should be able to do a save by hitting start button if I remember correctly. It has been a while since I played this on the PS3

Comment: @Dupree3 I'm used to playing the PC, which auto-saves every time you pass a Save station.  Is that not the case with the console versions?

Comment: @Powerlord there are autosaves on every version, but in the pause menu there should be another save option. Additionally there is a way to force a save by turning the badass rank on and off.

Comment: just choose character and select New "Class".

Answer (score 0):

On the PS3 and PS4, you can create as many new characters of any of the 6 classes as you like.

All you need to do is select "New Game" and select your character class - remember to name it so you'd recognise your character from your husband's.

Saving is pretty much continuous throughout the game - there are no slots, as such, only characters. As you've noted, there are checkpoints where your progress is saved. Your progress is also saved if you return to the main menu screen.

However - badass tokens and progress is shared across the profile - so you will start with all the badass buffs your husband has unlocked (and you will begin to generate new tokens and increase those buffs).

---

There is nothing stopping you creating a profile on the PS3 or the PS4 - these are free. Then you will have your own characters and badass progress in Borderlands 2.

However, if you want to play online on the PS4 you must also buy a PS+ account.